# Check that MariaDB is healthy and its status is ok after bootstrap

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My goal is to check MariaDB server is healthy after start. By healthy, i mean it's up and running and available to receive queries.
Is there any command which gives the expected result?

I've tried

```
SHOW STATUS;
```

from [MARIADB SHOW STATUS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-status/).

But none of these properties seems to give what i need.

Comment: after a start or restart mysql and mariadb can almost directly handle queries.. there isn't anny query to check if the database can handle queries or not... but you should be able to check with `SELECT 'healthy' FROM DAUL`

Comment: thanks. what is _DAUL_?

Comment: DAUL is a place holder a non existing table (dummy table) that exists in MySQL and Mariadb

Comment: `SELECT 'Healthy'` will also work.  Or, how about `SELECT NOW() AS 'Restarted at';`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I eventually went for _show databases;_ If got your responses right, it doesn't matter. Any query that succeeds would signify that _mysqld_ server is up and running.